# Android CARDSLIB: How to propagate card click to Spannable String?

Tags: android, spannablestring, cardslib

I'm trying to solve a problem I'm having with Cardslib and spannable text. Cards display correctly and each card shows the text I made spannable. Each spanned text has an overriden onClick listener that replaces current fragment.

The problem seems to be that Cardslib is catching the onClick event and it isn't propagated to the handlers inside the spannable text. Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance!